# Live video feeds through hosts' eyes in Westworld

Tags: westworld-tv

How come we don't see the park operators access video feeds through a host's eyes, while they do have full write access to their brains? (Random read access is uncertain, since instead of getting a sort of examinable debugging view of a host's brain, operators ask them questions that hosts can sometimes lie to.)

Answer (score 2):

**Because they don't need it.**

They already have 360 degree internal, external *and* satellite surveillance of the **whole** park.

Host POV cameras (such as eyes) wouldn't add anything extra.

[image]

Comment: And yet, for all their surveillance, operators sometimes cannot tell when a host going off its loop is doing so because it is accompanying a guest. When this occurs, they treat it so casually as to appear routine and somewhat common, but they have to send someone to make the determination and pick up the host. Host POV cameras could immediately determine whether a host is interacting with a guest. They also have to track missing hosts locally, they can't just pinpoint locate them via satellite. I think the answer is more likely they aren't that omniscient and they don't have the bandwidth.

Comment: @JDoe: good points. Also, if they managed to develop sufficient advanced AI to simulate humans to an uncanny degree (see Bernard) and trigger the [Good Samaritan Reflex](http://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/63507/in-westworld-how-can-guests-tell-the-difference-between-guests-and-hosts/63514#63514), how come they haven't scaled that to monitor the stimuli feeds from the hosts and intervene way more often and earlier?